# How to get value from Firebase to recycleView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[this is a picture of firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeB26.png)[this is the image of log which i am getting in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usDCo.png)

```
mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mRef=mDatabase.getReference("items").child("0").child("snippet");
mChildEventListner = new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            CategoriesModelClass user = dataSnapshot.getValue(CategoriesModelClass.class);
            Log.d("kkk", "" + user);
            title_description.add(user);
        }
        categoriesRecycleView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is my code from `activitymain` and I don't know should I fire query for title and description or it it will fetch it from the for loop?

this is the code of my model class

```
public class CategoriesModelClass {
    String title,description;

    public CategoriesModelClass(){

    }

    public CategoriesModelClass(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and i am try to set this data in my recycle view i need only title and description

Comment: Show us a screenshot with everything exposed, even `thumbnails`. Also show us the class `CategoriesModelClass `

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: Where is the screenshot of the database (exposing everything even the `thumbnails` node)? Sow me also adapter code aslo.

Comment: https://github.com/krushi-21/hello-world.git this is github link for all files can check for me

Comment: Add the images to question directly not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of `description` and `title`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference snippetRef = rootRef.child("items").child("0").child("snippet");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        CategoriesModelClass user = dataSnapshot.getValue(CategoriesModelClass.class);
        Log.d("kkk", "" + user.getTitle());

        //Get the values out of the user object
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
snippetRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, there is no need to loop over the `snippet` node, and this because we need to get the data according to type of object that is stored.

If there will be more than one items in the `0` node, then please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference zeroRef = rootRef.child("items").child("0");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            CategoriesModelClass user = ds.getValue(CategoriesModelClass.class);
            Log.d("kkk", "" + user.getTitle());
        }

        //Get the values out of the user object
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
zero.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: no errors come but i don't get data in recycle view

Comment: Is `Log.d("kkk", "" + user);` printing something in the glocat?

Comment: Yes Log.d("kkk"," "+user); printing kkk and "name of app"categoriesmodelclass@325326

Comment: yes i try you updated code but it give me the same error

Comment: i just attached picture of it

Comment: That's not an error, those are the addresses of the objects from the memory. I modified the log statement to this `Log.d("kkk", "" + user.getTitle());`. Check again my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: stil getting error https://github.com/krushi-21/hello-world.git this is my github code for all files can check this for me please.

Comment: If you are using `Log.d("kkk", "" + user.getTitle());`, what is the error that you get?

Comment: App will carsh and it don't give any error in logcat

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: It crash bcoz of for loop